# Returning a processed String of an Enum on Swift iOS

Tags: ios, string, swift, enums

I was just creating a localization module for my project, and as I'm new to Swift I had an idea of if the following was possible.

I have an enum like this:

```
enum Localizations : String
{
    case StringId1 = "string_to_translate_1"
    case StringId2 = "string_to_translate_2"
    case StringId3 = "string_to_translate_3"
    var localized : String {
        return NSLocalizedString(self.rawValue, tableName: nil, bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle(), value: "", comment: "")
    }
}
```

With this enum I can have the localized string with this command:

```
let myString = Localizations.StringId1.localized
```

But when you have to put lots of strings the .localized it's like redundant as you already have Localizations before.
So what I'm looking for is if I can do something like this:

```
let myString = Localizations.StringId1
```

And myString would be something like "Press Button to Continue"

I have managed to do something working, but not in all cases.

Found in this link: https://appventure.me/2015/10/17/advanced-practical-enum-examples/
On the 'Advanced Enum Usage Protocols' Step it suggests a modification like the following would get what I want:

```
protocol CustomStringConvertible {
  var description: String { get }
}

enum Trade: CustomStringConvertible {
   case Buy, Sell
   var description: String {
       switch self {
       case Buy: return "We're buying something"
       case Sell: return "We're selling something"
       }
   }
}

let action = Trade.Buy
print("this action is \(action)")
// prints: this action is We're buying something
```

My modifications are theses ones:

```
protocol CustomEnumString {
    var localized: String { get }
}

enum Localizations : String, CustomEnumString
{
    case StringId1 = "string_to_translate_1"
    case StringId2 = "string_to_translate_2"
    case StringId3 = "string_to_translate_3"
    var localized : String {
        return NSLocalizedString(self.rawValue, tableName: nil, bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle(), value: "", comment: "")
    }
}
```

But when printing it if shows me the enum literal, and when passing to a function the compilers tells me it's invalid:

```
let localizedString = Localizations.StringId1
print("localization: \(localizedString)")
// prints: "localization: StringId1"

// note: AlertStrings is an struct with two strings
// this fails to compile saying that cannot convert value of type 'Localizations' to expected argument type 'String'
let alertStrings = AlertStrings(title: Localizations.StringId1, message: Localizations.StringId2)
// this one works, but it's not the purpose I had in mind
let alertStrings = AlertStrings(title: Localizations.StringId1.localized, message: Localizations.StringId2.localized)
```

So... in short, I would like to be able to do this:

```
let localizedString = Localizations.StringId1
print("localization: \(localizedString)")
// prints: "localization: Press Button To Continue"

let alertStrings = AlertStrings(title: Localizations.StringId1, message: Localizations.StringId2)
```

But in the enum I only would like to specify literals once, not first on case's and later inside a switch.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a [very good article](https://medium.com/@mendibarouk/enhance-your-localized-capabilities-on-your-ios-applications-d3ba17138077) about localization in Swift for a robust architecture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**phelgo**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3700878/phelgo), A member of NSBarcelona just told me about this, and works perfectly!

> ```
> enum Localizations {
>     static let StringId1 = NSLocalizedString("string_to_translate_1", comment: "")
> }
>
> let myString = Localizations.StringId1
> ```
>
> It may look unfamiliar to have an `enum` with no cases, but we get to
>   keep all of its safety (and code completion), while still preventing
>   `Localizations` from being instantiated by mistake (if it was a
>   `struct`)

Comment: For such purpose, another valid approach is to have a `struct` with all your strings as computed variables (`static var`). For the ones that might be formatted then use static methods.

Answer (score 0):

Conform your `enum` to `CustomStringConvertible` and rename `localized` to `description`:

```
enum Localizations: String, CustomStringConvertible
{
    case StringId1 = "string_to_translate_1"
    case StringId2 = "string_to_translate_2"
    case StringId3 = "string_to_translate_3"

    var description : String {
        return NSLocalizedString(self.rawValue, tableName: nil, bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle(), value: "", comment: "")
    }
}

let alertStrings = AlertStrings(title: Localizations.StringId1.description, message: Localizations.StringId2.description)
```

Comment: Thanks! But it doesn't work :(
I've modified the post with those changes for others to see it.

Comment: `Localizations.StringId1` is of type `Locolizations`. Swift won't cast it to `String` automatically. You either call `rawValue` or `description` to get a `String` from the enum

Comment: Yup, what I wanted to do was calling directly to the enum and it returning the localized String by itself.